# Is it permitted for a Jew to accept an invitation by the Pope to attend mass

Tags: halacha, christianity, current-events

The chief rabbi of Rome received a special invitation from Pope Francis to attend a special mass on March 19.[VINNews article](http://www.vosizneias.com/126232/2013/03/14/vatican-city-pope-pledges-good-relations-with-jews/). Normally, a Jew is not even allowed to visit a church, much less a religious service.  But the Pope is a head of state, and the leader of the world's largest Christian movement, raising the issue of kavod hamalkus.  Also, the rabbi would be going in an official capacity to promote good Jewish-Catholic relations.  Do those facts give the rabbi a basis for going? What halachic theory can he rely upon?

Comment: I would think that the halacha of not going into a church would not get overridden just on the basis of fostering good relations. I have absolutely no source for this, and is therefore not posted as an answer.

Comment: If anything, quite the opposite. Since it's so public the Rabbi should be extra careful to strictly observe everything.

Comment: There is ample precedent historically of top Rabbis going to attend high level government events in churches. Whether the leniency is necessary now that there isn't the same level of animosity/competition between the religions is a good question.

Comment: @DoubleAA, there is a big difference between attending a government event in a church and a church service, even if the later is preformed by a head of state.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu 1) I think you don't appreciate the amount of historical precedents. 2) Even if it isn't a mass, funerals, marriages and such can also be considered religious services (YMMV for different sects).

Comment: @Yirmeyahu I recall that the chief rabbi gf England went to Westminster Abby for the wedding of Prince Charles and Diana. At the time it was explained by kavd hamelek.

Comment: One of the videos on torahcafe.com of the discussion between Dennis Prager and Chief Rabbi Jonathan Sacks is about whether Rabbi Sacks would walk into a church or take part in a Christian religious ceremony. His answer was no, and he talks about how they arranged for him to go first at one of the inter-faith ceremonies, so that it would not be a problem. If I recall correctly, he discussed the Westminster Abby mentioned by @BruceJames, but he was not in the chapel. It is one of these videos, I don't remember which one: http://www.torahcafe.com/scholar/mr-dennis-prager_0000000234.html

Comment: @Menachem Prince Charles. Was married before Rabbi Saks became Chief Rabbi. That rabbi was in Westminster Abby.

Comment: @BruceJames: Then it was something else in an Abby of some sort, I can't remember exactly and I don't remember which of the videos it was.

Comment: @menachem The chief rabbi at Prince Charles' wedding was Rabbi Sir Emanuel Jacobowitz.  I remember seeing him on TV and wondering how he could be in a church and a British friend told me it was a Kavof hamelech issue.

Answer (score 3):

Rome's chief rabbi, Rabbi Riccardo Di Segni, [will attend](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6CZ2XfMrlY) Pope Francis' installation mass.  But his attendance will not be without precedence:  Rabbi Di Segni, who took the chief rabbi position in 2001, [attended the funeral mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dignitaries_at_the_funeral_of_Pope_John_Paul_II#Religious_leaders) for Pope John Paul II. He wasn't the only Orthodox Jew there.  Oded Wiener, director general of the Chief Rabbinate of Israel, represented the Chief Rabbinate at the funeral.  Rabbi Shear-Yishuv Cohen, Chief Rabbi of Haifa, also attended.  Rabbi Di Segni was invited to attend the 2005 installation mass for Pope Benedict XVI, but [declined the invitation](http://www.haaretz.com/news/pope-invites-chief-rome-rabbi-to-installation-on-first-day-of-passover-1.156726) only because the mass was during Pesach.

The sources I cited do not give an explanation as to how Rabbi Di Segni, or any Orthodox Jew, can attend any Catholic mass, whether it is for a papal burial or the installation of a new Pope.  But the Chief Rabbinate's decision to send their director general to John Paul II's funeral mass, would appear to say that there is indeed an exception to Rabbi Metzger's strong position on Jews entering a church (Rabbi Metzger was the Ashkenazic Chief Rabbi at the time).  The exception is likely because the Pope is (a) a head of State, and (b) highly influential in Jewish-Christian relations around the world -- therefore maintaining favorable relations with him is essential for the safety to the Jewish people and Israel.

Some insight into Rabbi Di Segni's rationale may be gained by examining Rabbi Haskel Lookstein's [rationale for attending](http://www.vosizneias.com/26285/2009/01/25/new-york-rabbi-lookstein-in-letter-defends-participating-interfaith-services-in-a-church/) a service honoring President Obama's first inauguration at Washington's National Cathedral, an Episcopalian church.  Rabbi Lookstein gave the following reasons:

- The event was not an interfaith dialogue or an interfaith meeting.  Rather he viewed his invitation from President Obama -- "a man of incredible importance to the fate of our holy community" -- as an invitation to pray with the President.  Because representatives of other religions would be there, "I felt that the interests of our Orthodox community would be hurt if no one from our community participated."  He used the opportunity to remind the President that he had told Israelis in Sderot "If anybody would shoot rockets into my house while my daughters were sleeping, I would do anything in my power to make sure they wouldn’t do it again."
- He said the Shulchan Aruch, at Yoreh Deah 178:2, notes that a person who needs to be close to the government may wear even the Torah-prohibited garments of a gentile in order to represent the Jewish community well.  He said that the prohibition to entering a church also relates to appearances of impropriety, rather than being an actual impropriety, and, unlike the prohibition to wear the clothes of gentiles, is a rabbinic prohibition and therefore more easily waived.
- Rabbi Lookstein cited to the precedents of English chief rabbis appearing at Westminster Abby when invited by a king or queen, and also noted that the Chief Rabbi of Haifa attended the funeral of Pope John II (see above).
- He cited that the Tzitz Eliezer gave a specific heter to Rabbi Michael Broyde to enter a Christian house of worship during services at the behest of the Israeli government, which considered his attendance to be an important state matter.  The Tzitz Eliezer just advised Rabbi Broyde to wear his kipah and look as rabbinic as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Chief Rabbi of Israel Rabbi Yona Metzger [answered](http://api.ning.com/files/geUeDXYA8ucqFDg1ceqSsYzzIy5RADJoMZDOI%2a7HLqlbLzR9AeWu15Z7EAdtH-ahTXLf0qmazSoPwp%2a-RsmU5HDyCuA3efXf/file.PDF) a shailah on **entering** a church in clear terms and gave sources for his decison.

> (my translation) “Even where the result of non-attendance would be
>   unpleasantness or hatred on a personal or diplomatic level
>   contemporary poskim forbid it. Only in the case of danger to life would
>   there be permission.”

Rabbi Riskin [distinguished](http://api.ning.com/files/yFUgNNi6vXr4cwVqBynhQtHtLEjnVCFMfxZEwXekm8bME7V9O60q%2aPULJ6UbGEPHu5L6cVd48cOb8SYaUMZteCRGgXDTeqbw/Answerriskinchurch.jpg) between **entering** churches not containing icons or statues (certainly permissible) and those that do (permissible for study of art or to know how to respond to non-Jews in discussions). 
**Participating** in a service, he writes,  is forbidden except to learn as above or to prevent a desecration of God’s name (eg Chief Rabbi Sacks and Prince William’s wedding).

Rabbi Riskin’s opinion and some responses to it can be seen [here](http://jewishisrael.ning.com/profiles/blogs/rabbi-riskin-oks-jews-to-enter).

Comment: A few years ago I asked Rabbi Yehiel Eckstein, who has raised millions of dollars for Israel from evangelical Christians, who gave him a heter to attend church services.  He told me he relied on his own opinion.  At least now he can cite to Rabbi Riskin.