# Does one make a Bracha when seeing the Pope?

Tags: halacha, blessing, gentiles, christianity, malchut-royalty

Is he considered either a king or a great non-Jewish scholar?

Comment: Hi, Aaron Ross, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for the bringing this question here. Although they do not directly answer your question, you may be interested in the following (somewhat) related questions: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/39040 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/39045 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27159 and this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37737.

Comment: On a lighter note, what's the proper blessing for the Czar? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKnOhjH1-9w

Comment: Additionally, consider the possibility that even if he is considered a monarch of sufficient caliber that a blessing would otherwise be recited, perhaps his status as head of the Catholic religion would render such a blessing inappropriate.

Comment: @Fred, the Queen of England is in a similar situation vis-a-vis the Anglican Church, so she would also have to be disqualified if that were the case.  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55929/does-one-make-a-bracha-when-seeing-the-pope#comment160770_59920

Comment: @Yishai I guess that's possible, but I'm more inclined to think that that case may be different because her primary and most distinctive role is not that of a religious leader. Further, I don't think she usually wears conspicuous symbols of her religion. So reciting the blessing wouldn't carry the appearance of reciting a blessing over someone in their role as leader of a foreign religion.

Answer (score 5):

The Pope is the [head of state and government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope) of the [Vatican City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City), which is an internationally recognised nation-state. As the Vatican even controls a small military ([The Swiss Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Guard#Pontifical_Swiss_Guard)).

As an absolute monarch, he has the capacity to exert control over the military (if he desires) and is technically capable of enacting capital punishments in accordance with Canon Law (Catholic Halacha). We may liken this with the President of the United States who has the power to [execute or commute capital punishment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55967/4504), for whom one says the berachah for seeing a king, according to R' Ovadia Yosef זצ”ל (see above linked answer).

Comment: I intentionally avoided probably his greatest power thereon, which is of course pursuant to being Catholic. I'll edit in my other rationales.

Comment: Can you cite a source for the existence of capital punishment within Canon Law and the Pope's discretion thereon?

Comment: For the scholar blessing, the commentaries on Shulchan Aruch clearly say it has to be a wisdom classically recognized by Judaism, e.g. mathematics, medicine, or music; "not an expert on a foreign faith."

Comment: @Shalom, what I meant was that his greatest power over life and death is the ability to damn or save individuals (through Yoshke)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I've never learned hilchot haCatolikim, but I know that there are capital punishments for heresy, among other things in the Canon Codes. I would be more accurate if I had better knowledge of the sources.

Comment: *Historically* the church certainly carried out executions (inquisition trials, witch trials, etc), and sponsored or condoned widespread killing (crusades). Whether it has these powers under its religious law nowadays I don't know, but if they could justify such actions in the past and they claim their law is from God (and, presumably, therefore not flawed), it seems reasonable to assume their law still supports this. Also there's "papal inerrancy" [sic].

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by citing a rabbinic authority who confirms your speculation.

Comment: Being a religious figure could likely change the result. You did not discuss that in your question. You can at least stipulate that this might change the Halacha.

Comment: @Shalom, we can certainly make the bracha for a great scholar on the current pope, him having a masters in climatology, AFAIK, and all.

Comment: Pope Francis today outlawed capital punishment (he still has the power to reinstitute it tomorrow fwiw)

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard as much. I will b"n address that soon

Answer (score -4):

You said correctly that one makes a blessing on a king and on a great non-Jewish scholar.

A king is a head of state. The Poskim debate if one recites this blessing on a president or prime-minister. The blessing is definitely not recited on a powerful person who is not a head of state.

A great non-Jewish scholar is defined as one who has exceptional knowledge in one of the sciences.
See [Blessings on Wise Men and Kings](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2013/02/archives-hilchos-birchas-hariyah.html).

The pope does not meet either condition. There is no blessing for a respected religious leader of a (non-Jewish) religion.

Comment: The pope is the king of Vatican city

Comment: @ClintEastwood, the Pope is the monarch of Vatican city, but as Prince not King. IIRC though, the _beracha_ on seeing a king was recited for reigning German Princes pre-unification.

Comment: [[Vatican City\] is the smallest internationally recognized independent state in the world by both area and population. It is an ecclesiastical ... state ruled by ... the Pope.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City), so this answer is suspect on the facts. Is his status as ruler sufficient to reach the Halachic definition of a King for the purposes of this Bracha? I don't know.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon. There does seen to be a popular conception that princes serve under kings, but this is not necessarily true. Both Monaco and Andorra are principalities, ruled by a princes who are monarchs in their own right. (Andorra is a bit of a special case, mind you.)

Comment: Sure, @TRiG; halachikly he's a _melech_ whatever the title is—which is why (as I said) the Reichsfürsten would have the bracha made for them.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, note on your comments: most of the fürsten changed their titles to "könig" (King) after the dissolution of the Holy Roman Empire in 1806. On the other hand, many of the German monarchs maintained their titles during the Imperial Period (they each also had their own *de jure* militaries, so one could probably still say the beracha on seeing the kings of Bayern, Württemberg, and Sachsen)

Comment: @Yishai, I wrote up a new answer based on yours and J.C. Salomon's comments here, as well as some other information which was brought elsewhere on J.SE

Comment: I hold by what I said. In the absence of a compelling source proving otherwise, I don't think Halachah would recognize the Pope as head of state unless he actually exerts his secular power.