# Can a tour guide for Christian groups cite Christian verses as part of his job?

Tags: halacha, christianity, employment

Someone I know (Jewish, of course ;-) is a tour guide in Israel. He specializes in guiding Christian Pilgrim groups. They visit primarily Christian sites. Usually, as part of explaining a tourist place, the guide recites verses from the Gospels that refer to Jesus and Christian principles and beliefs.

Does citing such verses pose any halachic problems? The guide has no belief or attachment to any Christian principles. He uses these verses merely as means of contextualizing the site the group is visiting.

(Please do not focus on other possible problems such as whether he can enter a church. There are debatable opinions on this.)

Comment: By "tourists" did you mean "terrorists"? Because the only debate I know of about entering churches surrounds if you can do so to save your life (we rule it is permitted in that case if not a time of oppression: http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.157.3)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I did mean "tourists". The debate regarding church entry for Jews is a "sidebar". I found a lengthy article about 2 years ago regarding some permissibility for Jews to enter Churches, and, it stated that 1 or 2 notable Rabbanim did this in the past. It may be a while for me to locate this article, if I can, at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA I couldn't locate the article, but much was  similar to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27164/5275. I realize that the various heterim are for specific cases, but one of them mentions churches not containing idols of which most of the guide's sites apply, as there are a number of excavated sites as these in Israel. Also, it might be argued that by entering churches as part of his job he is "promoting good will", another one of the cited heterim. (If he didn't enter the Church while he was taking the group there, imagine what they would say about the guide, and, possibly all Jews!)

Comment: @DanF, he could also just not have that job. Making a parnassa wasn't one of the heterim there, although there is the precident of Moshe Rabbeinu's grandson (/sarc).

Comment: Anti missionary experts quote verses all the time, but use it to refute it call tuvia singer

Comment: @Yishai that's hindsight. I'm not implying that there is a heter to take the job. Now that he has the job, can he perform this activity for that purpose? For argument's sake, he didn't begin his guiding career with these groups. Now, it is his major parnassa, b/c non-Christian groups don't tour as much. Perhaps, there's an allowance post facto.